# Fantasy book about elves and spiders I read when a teen

Tags: story-identification, elves

Ok, so there was this book (it was actually a series) about elves, humans, and evil spiders, but I cannot for the life of me remember the title. I do however remember one scene in particular in which the love interest (male) of the main character (female) is found to have been killed by a spider. he is found in its web and has been disemboweled.

The year I read it would have been 2001-2002. The main character was a female elf, the main love interest was male and I think he was human. There was a war going on, the humans and elves had united against these spider people. It was book #1 in a series, but my school library only carried book 1. It looked new when I read it, or at least had not been checked out by anyone else. It was in a teen fantasy section.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Off to a great start but we could use a few more specific examples, for example, could you possibly provide a year for when you'd read it and when it may have been published? The above linked guide has some more details that would help with adding more details, it is very good.

Comment: Did this involve dark elves, or drow, aligned with the spiders?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Yes, that was going to be my first guess. ;)

Comment: Maybe??? I think so! My memories of it are so fuzzy but I loved it!

Comment: A lot of possible candidates to search https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/28172.Fae_Elven_Romance_Urban_Fantasy

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Daughter of the Drow](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786929294).

Protagonist is a female Drow (dark elf) from the D&D universe. Drow worship Lolth, the spider goddess, hence the appearance of spiders and spider like creatures throughout the novels. Her companion (and lover) is a human warrior.

If her human love interest is carrying a death sentence and a blunt sword, then this is it.